# PHP variables randomly becomes NULL

Tags: php, variables, null, hosting

For quite a while now we experience a very weird problem with our hosting server. Once a while (seems randomly) variables in PHP become NULLs.

In general everything works perfectly fine, but once a while it happens. All accounts on the server are affected and all PHP apps (including PHPMyAdmin, Wordpress our own scripts). We contacted our hosting company, but they are unable to find any solution.

I had few ideas, the most promising one was an issue with Suhosin. But I do not get any message in the log directly from it.

We made a simplest possible script to reproduce the error:

```
<?php
class Example
{

    protected $stringVar = 'this is a string value';

    public function accessParameter()
    {
        $error = false;
        if (isset($this->stringVar) && !is_null($this->stringVar)) {
            echo "string var : " . $this->toStringWithType($this->stringVar) . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "string var is not set\n";
            $error = true;
        }

        if ($error) {
            $logfile = dirname(__FILE__)."/random_bug_log.log";
            file_put_contents($logfile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n", FILE_APPEND);
            file_put_contents($logfile, $this->toStringWithType($this->stringVar) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }

    public function toStringWithType($var)
    {
        $type = gettype($var);
        return "($type) '$var'";
    }

}

$e = new Example();
$e->accessParameter();
```

Normal output:

```
string var : (string) 'this is a string value'
```

Output when the weird thing happens:

```
string var is not set
```

I open to any ideas or suggestions how to solve this problem. I guess the ultimate solution is to change the hosting company. I did not manage to create this issue on localhost or any other server.

---

Test piece that have been made, including your suggestions:

```
<?php
class Example
{
  protected $stringVar = 'this is a string value';

  public function accessParameter() {
    $error = false;
    if(isset($this->stringVar) && !is_null($this->stringVar)) {
      echo "string var : "
    .$this->toStringWithType($this->stringVar)
    ."\n";
    } else {
      echo "string var is not set\n";
      $error = true;
    }

    if($error) {
      $logfile = dirname(__FILE__)."/random_bug_log.log";
      file_put_contents($logfile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."   ", FILE_APPEND);
      file_put_contents($logfile, 
            $this->toStringWithType($this->stringVar) . "\n",
            FILE_APPEND);
    }

  }

  public function writeParameter() {
    $this->stringVar="variable assigned";
    if(isset($this->stringVar) && !is_null($this->stringVar)) {
      echo "string var : "
    .$this->toStringWithType($this->stringVar)
    ."\n";
    } else {
      echo "string var is not set\n";
      $error = true;
    }
  }

  public function toStringWithType($var)
  {
    $type = gettype($var);
    return "($type) '$var'";
  }


}

$e = new Example();
$e->accessParameter();
$e->writeParameter();
```

The output while the thing happens:

```
string var is not set
string var is not set
```

Comment: That is a very weird case. I would suggest seeing if they can change your server rather than changing company, it could be a sign of some intermittent hardware fault or impending failure of eg a memory chip

Comment: `isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL` [see here](http://ir2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). so you do not need to `is_null` check.

Comment: I've also encountered weird issue, such as randomly `strpos` returns `false` ...

Comment: @Amir Yeah, you can't tell `NULL` from **Undefined** without checking **Notice**.

Comment: @CertaiN - False or something like false, did you check with `===` ?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I just did `var_dump(strpos($haystack,$needle))`. When `$haystack` and `$needle` were fixed, it showed integer usually, but `false` rarely.

Comment: @zupapomidorowa - Does this problem also arise, if you somewhere write to the variable (at the moment it is static)?

Comment: The code we wrote is barely an example of the causes.
Some supplement outputs (that happen in parallel):

PHPMyAdmin

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/pma/libraries/Message.class.php on line 681
in #

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/pma/libraries/Message.class.php on line 681

Apparently foreach() argument goes wrong.

Comment: @martinstoeckli That's an interesting suggestion. We will try to write to it. The problem is that it's almost impossible to reproduce, because it happens randomly (99% of time it just works), so we need to catch another moment when the server is "in the wrong mood".

Comment: @martinstoeckli we can't write to the variable. Variable becomes not set.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem @zupapomidorowa

Comment: @Scopey It's been a while and this problem no longer concerns me, but I've seen this elsewhere as well couple of times, people were struggling. I'm not doing PHP anymore, so maybe it's completely gone with the new versions of the language. Will stay a mystery unsolved forever :)

Answer (score 0):

it is very strange problem.

it may not be a solution but worth to try;

```
protected $stringVar;

function __construct() {
    $this->stringVar = 'this is a string value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use !== instead of is_null to see if the variable is actually null.

`if (isset($this->stringVar) && ($this->stringVar !== null)) {`

or

`if (isset($this->stringVar) && (!empty($this->stringVar)) {`

should do the work too.

Answer (score 0):

In case of theses type of issues check with the value that you have in if condition and do what you want in else. Like in your situation do like:

```
 if(isset($this->stringVar) && ($this->stringVar == "this is a string value")) {

 }else{
  // your code here...
 }
```